# Using Watchers on props in vue3 Script Setup

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-props

I'm passing a prop to a component declaring in which state it is. I want to watch the prop and set the css accordingly. But it does not work, can someone telling me what I'm doing wrong?

```
<script setup>
  import { onMounted, reactive, ref, watch, watchEffect } from 'vue'

  const props = defineProps({
    title: String,
    date: String,
    state: String,
  })

  let cardStatus = ref('')

  watch(props.state, () => {
    if (props.state === 'finished'){
      cardStatus.value = 'border border-success'
    }
  })
</script>

<template>
  <div :class="'bg-main-light rounded-2xl w-full p-3 lg:px-5 ' + cardStatus"></div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try like following:

```
watch(
  () => props.state,
  (newValue, oldValue) => {
    if (newValue === 'finished') cardStatus.value = 'border border-success'
  }
);
```

Comment: It does not work like that, but I just found a way myself

Comment: @Lx45 It should work exactly the same way as in your post.

Comment: I agree - this is how to use `watch` on a prop, not sure why OP can't make it work, probably doing something wrong - probably because in the question he changes `cardStatus.value` and in his answer `cardStatusCard.value`

Comment: I agree with you, this answer is right. In my case I needed to use watchEffect because the watcher had to bet triggered initially.

Comment: I needed to add { immediate: true } in order to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to make it work.

```
<script setup>
  import { onMounted, reactive, ref, watch, watchEffect } from 'vue'

  const props = defineProps({
    title: String,
    date: String,
    state: String,
  })

  let cardStatusClass = ref('')
  
  watchEffect(() => {
    if (props.state === 'finished'){
      cardStatusClass.value = 'border border-success'
    }
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this way

```
const retWatch: any = toRef(props, 'props.state');

watch([retWatch], (newValue) => {
    console.log(newValue);
    
});
```